# Entity Framework setting datetime to null or min

Tags: sql, entity-framework, datetime

I'm using Entity Framework 5, Database First.

I am doing something I've done many times before, but for some reason it is not working.

My Table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivationQueue](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[username] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[email] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[ActivationRequested] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ActivationEmailSent] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[AccountActivated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ActivationAttempts] [int] NULL,
[ActivationKey] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
```

CONSTRAINT [PK_Activations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

This is the code I use to retrieve a particular row:

```
ActivationQueue accountActivation = DbSet.FirstOrDefault(a => a.username.ToLower() == userName)
```

When I use `DbSet.FirstOrDefault()` to get the first row, the ActivationEmailSent column is always returning `SQLDateTime.MinValue()` even though it has a correct value. The ActivationRequested column is always returning the correct value.

I've used SQL profiler, and when I run the below SQL I get the correct `DateTime` value back.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[username] AS [username], 
[Extent1].[email] AS [email], 
[Extent1].[ActivationRequested] AS [ActivationRequested], 
[Extent1].[ActivationEmailSent] AS [ActivationEmailSent], 
[Extent1].[AccountActivated] AS [AccountActivated], 
[Extent1].[ActivationAttempts] AS [ActivationAttempts], 
[Extent1].[ActivationKey] AS [ActivationKey]
FROM [dbo].[ActivationQueue] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (LOWER([Extent1].[username])) = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0         nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'someusername'
```

The thing that gets me is that the mappings for the `ActivationRequested` and `ActivationEmailSent` are identical as are the definitions ( I just used `updateModel` in the edmx). But `ActivationRequested` returns the correct value, while `ActivationEmailSent` returns `SQLDateTime.Min` ( `1753-01-01 00:00:00.000` )

I don't know whether this helps, but when I set the column to be nullable, it just returned null.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, that value isn't getting set.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem for anyone else that may come with this.

The model.store properties of the DateTime column had the **precision** attribute set to *None* whereas the Entity had the **precision** attribute set to *3*.

Changing the precision attribute to *none* for both fixed the issue.

Though I am still baffled why it worked for one of the columns in the first place, and not the other even though they had identical mappings.